# how to get values in different beans from single JsonNode in play framework controller

Tags: java, ajax, json, playframework

I am using play framework for Java. And I have jquery ajax to post my data (`String` representation of `JsonNode`). I am writing an action method in my controller class for serving this ajax call.

The problem I am facing is that, the data I am sending with jquery ajax has 10 textfield values. And I have 3 bean classes (viz., MyClass1`,`MyClass2`,`MyClass3`) that together have all these 10 variables to capture those textfield values. If I had only a single bean(say,`MyClass1`) with 10 variables defined in it, I could write something like:

```
JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
MyClass1 obj1 = Json.fromJson(json, MyClass1.class);
```

and easily access values from `obj1`.

But I have 3 beans and in first bean I've 3 variables, in the second 5 variables, and in the third 2 variables. This creates a problem.

How do i get these 10 textfield values in `MyClass1 obj1`, `MyClass2 obj2`, `MyClass3 obj3` in proper way and as required. In other words how do i achieve the spliting of `JsonNode`. Or something similar to get appropriate values in all the 3 beans.

Any help or any clue is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.
What can be done to get these?

Comment: One way I can think of is: I should make 3 different ajax call Sending  data values appropriate to MyClass1, MyClass2, MyClass3. But thats going to  be the last priority solution as 3 http requests are not better than single http request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer to this question is pretty simple. What I did was 
I added the following 2 lines in the bean `MyClass1`:

```
public MyClass2 m2;
public MyClass3 m3;
```

and I kept the code in my controller's json method same as it was earlier, i.e.:

```
JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
MyClass1 obj1 = Json.fromJson(json, MyClass1.class);
```

and in jquery I created a complex json `var` (NOTE: have a look at `data1` below):

```
var data1 = {
    "dataField1": dataField1,
    "dataField2": dataField2,
    "dataField3": dataField3,
    "data2": data2,
    "data3": data3
}

var data2 = {
    "dataField4": dataField4,
    "dataField5": dataField5,
    "dataField6": dataField6,
    "dataField7": dataField7,
    "dataField8": dataField8
}

var data3 = {
    "dataField9": dataField9,
    "dataField10": dataField10
}
```

and then while making ajax call simply passed `data1` as:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/myUrl/data1',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(data1),
    contentType: "application/json",
    ..
    ..
    ..
});
```

Now in the controller's json method, I could access `obj1.m2` and `obj1.m3`and could solve my problem. (No need to think about spliting `JsonNode`.)